# Firebase image retrieval not always showing up in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, firebase, file-upload, react-hooks, firebase-storage

I'm new to ReactJS and I created a project to do some concept application exercises.
Currently, I am on an exercise which consists of 1) loading then uploading images in Firebase, and 2) being able to retrieve them and display them in a page in ReactJS.
I manage without problem to load then upload an image. However, the retrieval and display of images does not work correctly.
In fact, I manage to recover the images, but the display is problematic.
For example, if I load an image (without even uploading it), the previously retrieved images appear correctly. However, if I refresh the page, they do not appear...

Here is the current (partial) code, including a Picture.ts type, a Picture.ts service and a Pictures.tsx page (the code is not executable, as I didn't want to include the Firebase API data, but that shouldn't be a problem) :
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-newton-zt16wo

Result :

[image]

As you can see with a console.error(), the images are well retrieved, but they don't appear in the interface.
What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Edit: I just found a fix.

I suspected  the problem came from the asynchrony of the API calls with respect to the rendering of the component, but I didn't know where exactly the problem was.
I just discovered that this is caused by the multiple asynchronous calls inside a loop, precisely at line 14 of the Picture.ts service.

To fix the problem, I replaced the following code:

```
try {
    const res = await listAll(ref(storage, COLLECTION_NAME));
    res.items.forEach(async (_data: any, index: number) => {
        try {
            const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `/${COLLECTION_NAME}/${_data.name}`));
            data.push({
                id: `${COLLECTION_NAME}-${index}`,
                name: _data.name,
                url
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

by the following code:

```
try {
    const res = await listAll(ref(storage, COLLECTION_NAME));
    await Promise.all(res.items.map(async (_data: any, index: number) => {
        try {
            const url = await getDownloadURL(ref(storage, `/${COLLECTION_NAME}/${_data.name}`));
            data.push({
                id: `${COLLECTION_NAME}-${index}`,
                name: _data.name,
                url
            });
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }));
}
```